# MySQL - Can't turn off skip-networking

Tags: networking, mysql

I'm trying to configure a freshly installed mysql server to listen on port 3306.

I've removed skip_networking, I have bind-address=127.0.0.1 and it completely ignores the config...

When I try `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'skip_networking'` I see it's still frustratingly ON.

`netstat -na | grep mysql` indicates it's listening on a random port, and yes, I do have port=3306 configured...
Exact line is:
`unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     45816    /var/run/mysqld/mysq d.sock`

Running on Ubuntu 12.04.2

Am I missing something REALLY obvious?

Comment: Are you certain you are editing the correct config file?  This has bitten me maaaaany times.

Answer (score 5):

**On OSX system using macports**

First kill your server if it is running.

```
mysqladmin shutdown -u root -p
```

Then Disable skip-networking from:

```
/opt/local/etc/mysql<YOUR_VERSION>/macports-default.cnf
```

Comment out the `skip-networking` line:

```
# skip-networking
```

Finally relaunch the server.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: The documentation states that macport-default.cnf will be replaced on next upgrade hence the need to override and not just modify.

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from your use of netstat.  The clue is that your sample output starts with "unix" instead of "tcp" (i.e., it's a Unix socket, vice a network port).  Instead of "netstat -an", try "netstat -antup" and grep for "mysql" or "LISTEN".

In other words, MySQL is no longer listening on a network port.  What you're seeing is a Unix socket, which isn't accessible from the network.  (Hope this helps.)

Answer (score 0):

**Working Code !!**

Go to Directory

```
/etc/mysql
```

open file `my.cnf` by

```
sudo nano my.cnf
```

or

```
vi my.cnf
```

Now comment below lines

```
#skip-networking=0
#skip-bind-address
```